# Where do I find my GCM sender ID?

Tags: google-developers-console

I'm trying to setup Pushwoosh as Parse is about to shut down. Pushwoosh is asking for my API Key and my GCM Sender ID. I didn't originally setup Parse and am not overly familiar with Google's developer portal.

Where do I find this information for my project?

I tried the API Key listed here "https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=MYPROJECT" but I see nothing about a GCM Sender ID.

Google is yelling at me on just about every page I find to upgrade to Firebase too but I don't have the time or need to migrate to that at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new rebranding of GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) to FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) finding the "GCM Sender Id" and the "API Key" has changed.

To get them:

**1-** Login to https://console.firebase.google.com

**2-** Create a new project for your app (or select your project and skip to step 3):

[image: Create new project]

2B- and fill the data on the popup

[image: fill the projectName on the popup]

**3-** On the 'Overview' screen, select "Add Firebase to your Web App" (or skip to step 4, if previously added)

[image: select Add Firebase to your web app]

3B- Just dismiss the resulting popup:

[image: just ignore the resulting popup]

  **4-** Go to the Project Settings page:

[image: Go to Project Settings: Settings wheel-->Project Settings]

  **5-** And finally to the "Cloud Messaging" tab. Your  "(GCM) Sender Id" and the "Server (API) Key"  are there:

[image: Go to Cloud Messaging tab]

Answer (score 0):

In case you already have an existing project do this first:

[Click on import google project (blue button on the right side of the screen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOUpL.jpg)

[Be sure to choose the correct country and click on "add firebase" (bottom right button)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrLlo.jpg)

After that please do the following as the answer above :)