# Google Cloud Messaging MismatchSenderId

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have an Android app that receives push notifications from Google Cloud Messaging. The app worked for several years.

It has been brought to my attention that push notifications no longer work on Android. Upon reviewing logs, I'm finding a "MismatchSenderId" error when POSTing to https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send.

I searched all my projects with my Google accounts and cannot find anything under this SenderID.

Is there anything that can be done to restore this project number?

Comment: check your SHA-1 is the same and check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294602/android-gcm-sender-id-how-to-get-it

Comment: Hi Lee. Unfortunately, I don't see how the SO community could help out here -- given that the issue is with finding (or restoring a project). I would recommend reaching out to Google Support directly. Cheers!